# The logic of my multithreaded application?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

I have to create three threads:

1. Reading strings from the console, ";" stops reading
2. Counting characters of those string
3. Displaying strings

And use pipes for communication.

The problem is that I have no idea how could this work. Do you have any advices? I've been thinking of something like this:

---

`Thread1` reads single string, then `Thread2` counts the character number, and `Thread3` saves the output in some external array.

And repeating that until all strings are read, to finally display all the output in `Thread3`.

---

But the problem with that is I can't get threads to run one by one in that order, and I don't know what that external array in `Thread3` could be.

Comment: Three threads that do what you describe makes no sense at all. Why do you "have" to create them?

Comment: Why do you need *pipes* if you are using threads? - they can communicate directly. If you want them to run *in order*, why do you need threads then?

Comment: I don't see a need for an `external array`.  Just display the strings one character at a time.  Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2):

Break down the problem per thread.

### Thread 1:

1. A loop that reads characters one at a time from stdin
2. Send the character to Thread 2 through pipe[1]
3. If the character read is not `'.'`, goto 1.
4. Otherwise, terminate thread.

### Thread 2:

1. A loop that reads characters one at a time from pipe[1]
2. Send the character to Thread 3 through pipe[2]
3. Increment a charCount variable.
4. If the character read is not `'.'`, goto 1.
5. Otherwise, print the charCount and terminate thread.

### Thread 3:

1. A loop that reads characters one at a time from pipe[2]
2. Print the character to stdout]
3. If the character read is not `'.'`, goto 1.
4. Otherwise, terminate thread.

### Thread *main()*

1. Create pipes
2. Create threads
3. Wait for threads to terminate.
4. terminate

As for the order the threads are created, I would code things so that it wouldn't matter.  However, my preference would be to start thread 3, then 2, then 1.